# Creating a Poll module in Sitefinity

Tags: module, sitefinity

What is the best approach to build a poll module in sitefinity?

Basically in the back end, I need the ability to create new polls with front end widget for voting and saving votes.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

regards,

joe

Answer (score 0):

There is a [poll widget](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/marketplace/publishers/telerik-inc/poll-widget-) available on the marketplace but its compatibility is listed as 4.x so I'm not sure if that works with your version of Sitefinity or not. There are a couple videos of people using it [here](http://youtu.be/TO5l6b68130) and [here](http://youtu.be/9byyxAOe3xQ).

Comment: Hi ben, thanks for the links. Appreciate it,This poll widget is based on forms module. I am trying to build a new custom module through module builder which will be called Polls where I should add the ability to create polls by allowing the add of question and multiple choices similar to the poll widget above.